# How DH-parameters is obtained for this manipulator?

Tags: robotic-arm, dh-parameters

So I'm trying to find DH parameters for the manipulator as shown in this picture:
[image]

I draw coordinate systems for each joint as:
[image]

And I got this DH parameters:
[image]

Is this solution correct? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is your coordinates system at the home configuration ?

Comment: @McLovin yes they are

Comment: i tried inputting these DH values to matlab, and matlab doesn't return the same robot. I will write an answer when I get time